# Highlighting form fields while validation

Tags: javascript

I was creating contact form which accept the email address. It highlight the email field in green if it is valid i,e. contains '@' symbol and red otherwise.
But i am not getting the output. Please find the attached code for reference.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#contact form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(e.currentTarget),
      $email = $form.find("#contact-email"),
      $button = $form.find("button[type=submit]");

    if ($email.val().indexOf("@") == -1) {
      vaca = $email.closest("form-group");
      $email.closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
    } else {
      $form
        .find(".form-group")
        .addClass("has-success")
        .removeClass("has-error");
      $button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $button.after("<span>Message sent. We will contact you soon.</span>");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It will be onchange validation or after submit?

Comment: As i click on submit button, if the email is invalid, the email field must be highlighted in red color, and if it valid it should highlight all fields in green and show the message.